# Django - отображать количество пользователей смотрящих трансляцию на данный момент

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование, backend, live

Я разрабатываю сайт на Django для сервиса с трансляциями спортивных игр. Нужно выводить количество пользователей которые на данный момент смотрят трансляцию. Просматривать трансляцию можно только после авторизации.

Кто-то может подсказать как реализовать это лучше всего?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По итогу пришлось использовать websockets(django channels). Но как оказалось это не столь сложно как мне показалось изначально.

consumers.py

```
import json
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer
from .models import Translation


class Watcher(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.accept()
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'type': 'start watch',
            'message': 'User started watching stream'
        }))
        pk = self.scope["url_route"]["kwargs"]["pk"]
        data = Translation.objects.get(id=pk)
        data.online += 1
        data.save()

    def disconnect(self, code):
        pk = self.scope["url_route"]["kwargs"]["pk"]
        data = Translation.objects.get(id=pk)
        data.online -= 1
        data.save()
```

javascript

```
let url = `ws://${window.location.host}/ws/socket-server/{{ pk }}/`
                            const viewStream = new WebSocket(url)
                            viewStream.onmessage = function (e) {
                                let data = JSON.parse(e.data);
                                console.log("DATA: ", data);

                            }
```

Этот код даст возможность отслеживать количество пользователей на каждой странице, но вам понадобиться еще прописать в моделях online.
Надеюсь мои поиски помогут еще кому то кроме меня.